# Centering hero image on zoom

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, zooming

I've browsed a whole lot of posts on here, some of which relate more closely to my issue than others; yet I've still to find a solution/explanation. -- Sorry if I've missed the answer somewhere!

Here goes.

I have this issue on with regards to a hero image on a site I'm creating, that I'd love to see resolved before I venture any further.

My issue is, that currently, on zoom, it goes towards the upper left corner, and adds a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom.

Ideally I'd like for the hero image to be centered when I zoom in with the browser, and for there to be no horizontal scrollbar.

Hopefully there's a simple fix, or something obvious I'm missing, and you lot could provide my feeble mind with an explanation as to what exactly it is that I'm not getting.

Below is provided the HTML and CSS I have so far. - Thanks in advance!

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 10px;
    
}

.hero_Image {
    height: 1080px;
    width: 1920px;
    background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/NVdZ3Ja.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;

    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box
    
}

.preview {
    height: 50rem;
    width: 1920px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    background: green;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>treadwell.io</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <section class="hero_Image">

        </section>
        <section class="preview">
            
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where's the bit that does the zooming?

Comment: Woops, updated the snippet so it doesn't contain an image located on my pc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
to fix your problem add this css to your file and your problem is that you let the width of sections overflowing
```

```css
  .hero_Image {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   background-image: url(https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/6c9e2ae9-7592-4de9-8ca9-2692bb908be7/svn/commercial-electric-specialty-meters-ms602h-64_1000.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   background-size:cover;
   border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
   position: relative;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }  

  .preview {
   height: 500px;
   width: 500px;
   margin-left: 10%;
   background: green;
   margin: 0 auto;
   overflow:hidden;
  }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>treadwell.io</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <style>
 </style>
    <body>
        <section class="hero_Image">

        </section>
        <section class="preview">
            
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, I attempted the same CSS you provided, thing is; I'd like for the image to have a fixed width size, so that it doesn't take up the entire screen when I zoom out.

Maybe it's not possible doing it like that, and not have the image move when I zoom in...

Comment: can you tell me what size you would like to add to  your  image ?

Comment: Using Chrome, I'd like for the image to be full screen at 100%, and progressively get smaller when you zoom further out, and just zoom in on the center when I go over 100%, if that makes sense.

Comment: Try using the above solution with the addition of `max-width: 500px` on the `.hero_Image`. Change 500px to whatever the largest width you'd like your image to appear.

Comment: loook I have modified the css you can try the new css that I set and its works

Comment: That'll take care of the initial scrollbar dilemma? Forgive me, I'm not near my pc currently...

Comment: @mohammedaamoum That's it! Can you tell me what you added/removed from the CSS just for future reference?

Comment: so I  added overflow: hidden to prevent scroll bar also I have changed the width of sections and if you want the sections be responsive I recommand for you to use media query that's will helps to make  your page responsive

Comment: @danielbernardi thanks for the help aswell man; if I could vote to answers, I would!